# Merging dataframes without changing values

Tags: r

I have two dataframes

```
df1 <- data.frame(c(1:10))
df2 <- data.frame(c(1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0)
```

I tried to merge them using this code:

```
merge(df1,df2,all = TRUE, sort = FALSE)
```

But my dataframe comes out really weird, there are 100 rows

I want the dataframe to look like this:

```
col1    col2
1       1
2       0
3       1
4       1
5       0
6       1
7       0
8       0
9       1
10      0
```

How can I do this?

Comment: That is not a `merge`, that is done with `cbind(df1, df2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with `cbind()`, which stands for column bind:

```
cbind(df1, df2)
```

Comment: Does this give desired results, with regards to column names?

Comment: yes, as long as the columns/data.frames have the same `length()` or `nrow()`

Comment: Don’t think I was clear, if you run this with the sample data provided in the question, the column names are not “col1”, “col2” as desired by OP

Comment: To me yes. Try this: ```df1 <- data.frame(col1=c(1:10))
df2 <- data.frame(col2=c(1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0))
cbind(df1, df2)
```

Comment: Yes, and see my comment to @cardinal40 about that it changes the data provided in the question...

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. In your question you did not define the names of the columns, but just the name of the data.frames

Comment: I am just pointing out, your answer does not provide the required output. Specifically, the column names.... But I suppose there is scope to assume a reasonable user will be able to rename the column names etc... Interesting regarding good practices anyway...

Answer (score 1):

You can just define a new data frame, and use `[,1]` to extract the columns from your existing data frames, this gives you the ability to name the columns.

```
data.frame(col1=df1[,1], col2 = df2[,1])               
#   col1 col2
#1     1    1
#2     2    0
#3     3    1
#4     4    1
#5     5    0
#6     6    1
#7     7    0
#8     8    0
#9     9    1
#10   10    0
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the formatting you want, with named columns:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(1:10))
df2 <- data.frame(col2 = c(1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0))
df <- bind_cols(df1, df2)
```

Comment: I believe this changes the existing data? By redefining the col names? If the data was such, the base R `cbind` would do.